# open CV with processing - Error

Tags: opencv, processing

I'm trying to work with the openCV library. I keep getting errors (I've tried to install both 32-bit and 64-bit processing, and followed the exact instructions online). This is the code I'm trying to run (the most basic one i think):

```
import hypermedia.video.*;        //  Imports the OpenCV library
OpenCV opencv;                    //  Creates a new OpenCV Object

void setup()
{

  size( 320, 240 );

  opencv = new OpenCV( this );    //  Initialises the OpenCV object
  opencv.capture( 320, 240 );     //  Opens a video capture stream

}

void draw()
{

  opencv.read();                  //  Grabs a frame from the camera
  opencv.absDiff();               //  Calculates the absolute difference
  image( opencv.image(), 0, 0 );  //  Display the difference image

}

void keyPressed()
{
  opencv.remember();              //  Remembers a frame when a key is pressed
}
```

This is the error I get: A library relies on native code that's not available. Or only works properly when the sketch is run as a 64-bit application.

Any help would be appreciated!, thanks

Comment: Guessing your working from this: http://createdigitalmotion.com/2009/02/processing-tutorials-getting-started-with-video-processing-via-opencv/

Did you install GStreamer/GSVideo?

Answer (score 0):

For the old school [OpenCV 1.0 wrapper](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/) make sure you install OpenCV 1.0 first.
So on Windows install the [OpenCV1.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/1.0/OpenCV_1.0.exe/download) and in the install tick the **Add <...>\OpenCV\bin to system PATH** checkbox when you install it, or manually add the PATH to environment variables.
On OSX it's a matter of installing the OpencV.framework. The Processing wrapper should work after that.

That wrapper is a bit outdated though. You might want to try Greg's [OpenCV Processing wrapper](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing)

[image: modern OpenCV Processing wrapper sample]

[image: modern OpenCV Processing wrapper sample]

[image: modern OpenCV Processing wrapper sample]

[image: modern OpenCV Processing wrapper sample]

[image: modern OpenCV Processing wrapper sample]

[image: modern OpenCV Processing wrapper sample]

[image: modern OpenCV Processing wrapper sample]

Comment: I don't think that's the answer - I'm getting the same error trying to use the WebCam, running on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: @DanBernier What's the error you're getting ? Can you run any of the Processing webcam samples (File > Examples > Libraries > Capture) ?

Comment: Actually, I suspect it was an unrelated problem. Sorry, I've forgotten the details, as I got it working a few months ago. I think I was looking for the wrong camera.

Comment: BTW @GeorgeProfenza, a hearty thank-you for pointing me to the Capture examples - that's a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what version of OpenCV you are using, the library hypermedia doesn't work for processing 2.0
If you want to continue with that code you need to get Processing 1.0 but I recommend to update the OpenCV library.