# UnsatisfiedLinkError using opencv for processing

Tags: opencv, processing

I'm calling:

```
Mat opencv_K= new Mat(3, 3, CvType.CV_32F);
```

in a [Processing](https://processing.org/) sketch and I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(III)J
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$2.run(PSurfaceJOGL.java:480)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(III)J
A library relies on native code that's not available.
Or only works properly when the sketch is run as a 32-bit application.
```

This error seems to me different from the one reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942608/open-cv-with-processing-error).

A minimal example is:

```
import processing.core.PVector;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType; 
import org.opencv.core.Core;
Mat opencv_K= new Mat(3, 3, CvType.CV_32F);
```

And the error in this case is somewhat similar:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(III)J
A library relies on native code that's not available.
Or only works properly when the sketch is run as a 32-bit application.
```

I'm using Processing 3 in an Ubuntu platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

Just add `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);` before the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying Greg's [OpenCV for Processing library](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing):

```
import gab.opencv.*;

import processing.core.PVector;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType; 
import org.opencv.core.Core;
Mat opencv_K; 

OpenCV opencv;

void setup(){
  opencv = new OpenCV(this,640,480);
  opencv_K = new Mat(3, 3, CvType.CV_32F);
  println(opencv_K);
}
```

Console output:

```
OpenCV for Processing 0.5.2 by Greg Borenstein http://gregborenstein.com
Using Java OpenCV 2.4.5.0
Mat [ 3*3*CV_32FC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x7fb86157f080, dataAddr=0x7fb861589e90 ]
```

Comment: any reasons to recommend it?

Comment: **pros**: Super easy to setup (Sketch > Import Library > Add Library > OpenCV for Processing), easy to access OpenCV functionalities (min/max brightness/face detection/background subtraction,etc.), OpenCV to Processing and back conversions (`Mat<->PImage`, `Point<->PVector`,etc.)ships with precompiled libraries for common OSes
**cons**: currently uses OpenCV 2.4.5.0 (needs manual update if newer functions are required), on more complex tasks, it's easier to skip most of the wrapper code and just convert PImage to Mat at the start, process with the typical Java OpenCV API, then convert back.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by simply initializing OpenCV object in the start which I was not doing already before using Mat e.g.`opencv = new OpenCV(this,500,500);`